# Bisection method error in R. Specifying midpoint and length

Tags: r, statistics, numerical-methods

Hi I'm trying to write the bisection method using R. I know there has been questions like this before, but my specific questions is that, how could I write the function if specifying the midpoint and length, but not a and b? Here is my code, but it gives me lots of error.

The reason why I want to specify the midpoint and length is that, if the initial interval does not contain the root, it could double the search length... like from (pt-h/2, pt+h/2) to (pt-3h/2,pt+3h/2).

Here is my codes.

```
f1<-function(x){exp(x)-1}

find<-function(pt,h,tol = 0.0001){
    if f1(pt-h/2)*f1(pt+h/2)<0{
       time = 1
       while (h>tol) {
         if f1(pt)*f1(pt-h/2)<0 pt+h/2<-pt
         if f1(pt)*f1(pt+h/2)<0 pt-h/2<-pt 
         time<-time+1
       }
     cat("Iteration time is ",time,"\n")
     cat("The root is ",md,"\n")
     cat("The real y of root is ",fmd,"\n")
    }
  }
```

Comment: you don't define `fmd` or `md`; what errors are you getting, exactly?

Comment: you don't update `h`, how do you expect the loop to finish?

Comment: ahh sorry. The last 2 lines should be not be md and fmd. It should return pt and fpt, which is the midpoint and the function value of midpoint.I forgot to change the name when I posted it. The errors shows unexpected symbols in some while and for loop.